# Selecting DataFrame rows based on comparison with other DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I Have two DataFrames like this:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [2],
    'number': [20]
})

df_B = pd.DataFrame({
    'words': ['Hello', 'world', 'aloha'],
    'id': [3, 4, 1],
    'number': [17, 18, 10]
})
```

I want to select only the rows from `df_B` for which the following criteria is met:

```
(df_B.id >= df_A.id ) & (df_B.number <= df_A.number)
```

For our case the result would look like this:

```
words            id             number
Hello            3              17
World            4              18
```

This seems to work when I compare against values of `df_A` as scalars but I want a better solution by comparing the dataframes. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: `by comparing the dataframes`, what do you mean? Multiple values in `df_A`? Then the comparisson would be ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need cross join for one `DataFrame`, so possible compare and filter:

```
df = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df2.assign(a=1), on='a')
df = df[(df.id_x >= df.id_y ) & (df.number_x <= df.number_y)]
```

Comment: Thankyou, it works. Appologies for the delay in checking the answer, had some computer issues.